# Not able to install anything in Ubuntu 12.04 Software Center

Tags: 12.04

As displayed in below image, I am having trouble in installing any software in ubuntu 12.04 software center. I am not able to cancel the 1st process ("searching"), though I have many times clicked to cancel it. And because of that process, I am not able to install any other packages.

If I try to install anything from the terminal I get

`E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`

How can I get rid of this situation??

[image]

Comment: could you post the output you get when installing from terminal?

Answer (score 0):

try **sudo apt-get install** command from the terminal, it might help

Comment: No from terminal also I am not able to install. I am getting the following error: "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?"

Comment: Do you have the Softwarecenter still open?

Comment: Yes. No matter if I close it or open it, the 1st process of "Searching" is always there. It neither completes the process nor allows me to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether apt-get is running with

```
ps ax | grep apt-get
```

If it runs you can kill it with

```
sudo kill -9 [pid]
```

If it still doesn't work and you are sure all processes that use this lock are closed (softwarecenter, any apt-get in consoles) you can delete the lock as a last resort

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

You might also need to remove the chache lock

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

After that you might have to run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

**Note that if something is still updating packages in the background (forgotten apt-get or softwarecenter) this can cause troubles**

Comment: I am mostly sure, but still how to check whether any update are carried out in background or not.?

Comment: edited to include that

Comment: Ohhk. I removed the lock file and cache. But after that when I tried to install anything, another error came. "E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem."

Comment: run sudo dpkg --counfigure -a forgot that in the anwser

Comment: Yes but still I am having that "searching" process in the software center. So not able to install from software center.

Comment: Close the softwarecenter run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade and try the softwarecenter again